# How do I transparently compress a directory?

Tags: hfs+, compression

I'd like to enable [HFS+ compression](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2009/08/mac-os-x-10-6/3/) for a directory, applying it to both the existing files in that directory and newly copied files. I expect to be able to read and write the contents of that directory normally.

Does HFS+ treat non-compressible files intelligently, say by trying to compress the first few KB of the file and bailing if it doesn't compress? I don't want non-compressible files expanding or their access significantly slowed down by compression and de-compression.

Is this possible to do out of the box in Yosemite? I'm also open to installing a third-party app (even a command-line one) to enable the compression, if I can then uninstall it later and have the directory retain the compression.

I found `afsctool`, but it hasn't had a release or update in an year and a half, and I don't want to use unmaintained software. Besides, `afsctool` works only for existing files, not newly copied ones.

Comment: not sure if this is a dupe or not, so I'll just post this link, see if it helps at all - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/50525/creating-an-automated-hfs-compressed-folder  Also http://superuser.com/questions/579371/does-os-x-support-disk-compression

Comment: I checked those, and this post is not a dupe of the first one, since I'm not interested in cobbling together a solution using scripts to compress newly added files. Besides, this question adds another consideration, which is that already compressed files should perform no worse.

Answer (score 6):

The compression is supported by HFS+ file-system out of box, however macOS by default doesn't compress any files.

---

#### `afsctool`

There is a [`afsctool`](https://github.com/jrk/afsctool) command-line utility which can transparently compress the files, for example:

```
afsctool -c some_dir
```

Install via: `brew install afsctool`.

---

#### `ditto`

When copying files, use `ditto`, e.g.

```
ditto --hfsCompression src dst
```

> When copying files or extracting content from an archive, all the content will be compressed if appropriate.

To check whether a file is compressed using HFS+ compression or not, you can use [`hfsdebug`](https://web.archive.org/web/20210616020646/http://osxbook.com/software/hfsdebug/). See: [Compress files with HFS+ compression](https://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20090902223042255).

---

Related: [Transparent file compression apps for macOS](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/45010/3474).

Comment: Clusters hasn't been updated in years and I've had numerous troubles with it in more recent versions of macOS, including corrupting files it has compressed.

Comment: Clusters has worked wonders for me up to and including Sierra. It's current not working in High Sierra but I'm hopeful it will be updated as APFS still supports HFS+ compressed files.

Comment: According to the manufacturer, Clusters has been discontinued: http://www.latenitesoft.com/clusters/index.html

Comment: I'm working on a replacement of my own.