# Copy directory structure and symlink files (alternative to `cp -as`)

Tags: macos, terminal, folders, symlink

I'm looking for how to recursively copy a directory structure and then fill the copy with symlinks to the corresponding files from the source directory. This has [a simple solution in Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196537/how-to-copy-a-folder-structure-and-make-symbolic-links-to-files) in the form of `cp -as`, but `cp` seems to lack the `s` option on macOS Mojave.

The underlying goal is to automate the process of making applications that do not reside in `/Applications` show up in Launchpad.

What would be an elegant, preferrably future proof, alternative to this on macOS?

From doing `brew search cp` I get the impression that Homebrew does not have an alternative version of `cp`.

---

### Update

#### Additional information

I'm currently running this regularly, but I want to improve it by making it recursive:

```
ln -s /<Source app directory>/*.app /Applications
```

It also has to preserve the directory structure because:

1. Subdirectories are used to manage sets of applications that are to be excluded from backup, without having to manually change Time Machine settings every time I add a new application. For instance, games are large and do not need to be backed up. Same goes for versions of Xcode.
2. A mere symlink to a subdirectory does not include its linked target's applications in Launchpad.
3. A symlinked directory would prevent creating a real directory with the same name. That prevents the source and destination directories from being organised identically.

Comment: Why would you do this on macOS rather than use hard links? This feels more like an XY question, but I think you’ll get the cp you want from homebrew and I’ll add a “use `ditto`” answer to review things like notarization, xattr, ACL and quarantine which are all relevant for `/Applications` and macOS changes coming past the initial Catalina release.

Comment: @bmike You can't use hard links over file system boundaries. I don't really see a point in not placing apps in /Applications unless they're on a separate volume. Not familiar with `ditto` -- I'll check it out, thanks. No plans to update to Catalina within the forseeable future though, since I have games that I want to be able to run.

Comment: Perfect - sounds good Andreas - you’ve got time then to suss out APFS / HFS+ and the tools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GNU version of `cp` is part of `coreutils`

```
brew install coreutils
```

It gets installed as `gcp` to avoid conflicts with the BSD version of `cp` (which behaves differently for some arguments).

Comment: Nice detective work! I was wrong. I'll try it out.

Comment: This worked as advertised. Some advice to others trying this: don't do what I did and forget that `.app`s are directories ‍♀️‍♂️ Back to the drawing board...

Comment: @Andreas You might get some ideas on how to accomplish what you want by posting a new question describing the problem you want to solve and any constraints a solutions needs to consider.

Comment: Thanks. I'm considering it, just have to research existing options. I think https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/343601/109837 might hold the answer.

Comment: This answers the question asked - how to use `cp` however, there’s more at stake specifically with /Applications in terms of quarantine bits, notarization, etc. I strongly recommend people use `ditto` if they know they are on macOS for things that gatekeeper and code signing / notarization will validate. Over time, `cp` surely will handle things like making APFS clones rather than just copying the data a second time, working harmoniously with APFS transparent compression, working harmoniously with APFS snapshots and per file based encryption, etc.. But today, `ditto` is the tool for this job

Answer (score 1):

If you are on APFS - I would use `ditto` which preserves all the metadata, understands APFS transparent compression and handles all of the native items as well as POSIX items like suid/sgid

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40974029/what-is-difference-between-cp-and-ditto-command-on-osx
- [How do I transparently compress a directory?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193893/how-do-i-transparently-compress-a-directory)

This will save you headaches with tools that don’t preserve code signing, notarization, quarantine bits and more when those all become mandatory in future releases.

- https://eclecticlight.co/2019/11/12/preparing-for-new-security-rules-how-signatures-can-get-stripped/

Comment: The links reside on APFS and point to HFS+. Does `ditto` create symlinks?

Comment: @Andreas It handles sym links well for my needs, but I don’t run as `cp -as` so test that first, but I’m not sure if you’re crossing disks and mixing / matching APFS with HFS+ - I’d be surprised if you couldn’t use ditto, but might not need to.

Comment: `ditto` doesn't create symlinks instead of copying, so I'm not sure it behaves the same way as (GNU)`cp -as`. But then I also not fully sure I understand the intention of the whole operation, so it might be just right for the job after all :-)

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. @nohillside The intention was to make apps not in /Applications, but in another identically organised Application directory, show up in Launchpad. But since `.app`s are directories, which I stupidly forgot about, this one `gcp` operation is not enough. I think I'm looking at first duplicating the directory structure with something similar to `rsync --exclude '*.app/' --include '*/' --exclude '*'` and then symlink all *.app directories as a second phase.